# performance qt with gpu graphics card

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

can any one help me explaining the qt performance with graphics cards.
how qt detect the usage of graphics card. if we deploy nvidia/ati cards of 4gb ram  how our normal QGraphicsview program will access the Graphics features.
whether we need any special macros or function calls to access the graphics in qt application ..? 
im right now using windows 7 , qt-4.8.

Comment: You are able to use OpenGL with QGraphicsView, http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html

Comment: thx for the comment .. this is my actual doubt .. only in opengl QGLWidget viewport  we can see good performance ..? and not in the normal viewport of QGraphicsView .?

Comment: How did you configure your QGraphicsView? Add the code snippet to the question. It only uses OpenGL if you configure it accordingly, see phoad's link.

Comment: Frank  first thx for the reply . Im using graphicsView->setupViewport(new QGLWidget(fmt)) and its clear to me ..but  i want to know 1. How qt detects the new GPU card (say NVIdia) i installed now. 2. can u explain me clearly about how mkspec of qt detects the new GPU libraries in qt opengl module. can u please explain me  how i can configure qt opengl with the GPU i deploy.

Comment: I too would love to know how Qt detects and confirms the use of Graphics hardware!